# ./configure --dest-cpu=x64 not setting correct target architecture on Mac OS 10.7

Tags: macos, node.js, osx-lion

#### Background:

I originally compiled node with no issues on Mac OS Lion, with the standard compile procedure, but when calling `process.arch` noticed it was returning `ia32`. I can only assume the default build configuration is for a 32-bit architecture.

#### Question:

When calling the `--dest-cpu=x64` option, the configure output shows:

```
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                   'defines': [],
                   'include_dirs': [],
                   'libraries': ['-lz']},
'variables': { 'host_arch': 'ia32',
             'node_debug': 'false',
             'node_install_npm': 'true',
             'node_prefix': '/usr/local',
             'node_shared_cares': 'false',
             'node_shared_v8': 'false',
             'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
             'node_use_isolates': 'true',
             'node_use_openssl': 'true',
             'node_use_system_openssl': 'false',
             'target_arch': 'ia32',
             'v8_use_snapshot': 'true'}}`
```

This suggests node detects, and still compiles to a 32-bit architecture. Is this a bug in the configuration filed, I would expect node to compile to 64-bit on a native 64-bit system? The only other thing I can think of is that the V8 snapshot is 32-bit; would this mean compiling my own version of V8 for a 64-bit arch?

Comment: x86_64 is not a valid option either. There's definitely some [uncertainty related to this in the configure script](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/configure#L112). May just have to wait this one out.

Comment: [Submitted to issue github repo](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2535). We'll see where this leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the guys working on node fixed my [reported issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2535) within 10 hours. Fantastic work. Question answered, issue resolved (untested).